# I am not able to output the best selected features using random forest?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have made random forest classifier which has threshold value = 0.15 but when I try to iterate over the selected model it does not output the best selected features.

Code:

```
X = data.loc[:,'IFATHER':'VEREP']
y = data.loc[:,'Criminal']

import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

    # Split the data into 30% test and 70% training
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)

# Train the classifier
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Print the name and gini importance of each feature
for feature in zip(X, clf.feature_importances_):
    print(feature)

# Create a selector object that will use the random forest classifier to identify
# features that have an importance of more than 0.15
sfm = SelectFromModel(clf, threshold=0.15)

# Train the selector
sfm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The code below does not work:

```
# Print the names of the most important features
for feature_list_index in sfm.get_support(indices=True):
    print(X[feature_list_index])
```

I am able to get the feature importance of each feature using Random forest  classifier but not using threshold value. I think `get_support()` is not the right method.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new `X` data set containing the most important features:

```
X_selected_features = sfm.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

To see the feature names:

```
features = np.array(list_of_feature_names)
print(features[sfm.get_support()])
```

if `X` is a Pandas.DataFrame:

```
features = X.columns.values
```

Comment: I couldn't understand you. What should I insert in my code because the for loop does not print the most significant features.

Comment: I am using `sfm =  SelectFromModel(clf, threshold=0.15)` and `sfm.fit(X_train, y_train)` so no need of  this `X_selected_features = sfm.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: What is `list_of_feature_names` ?

Comment: can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345578/how-to-decide-threshold-value-for-selecting-features