# How to decide threshold value in SelectFromModel() for selecting features?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using random forest classifier for feature selection. I have 70 features in all and I want to select the most important features out of 70. Below code shows the classifier displaying the features from most significant to least significant.

Code:

```
feat_labels = data.columns[1:]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)

# Train the classifier
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

importances = clf.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

for f in range(X_train.shape[1]):
    print("%2d) %-*s %f" % (f + 1, 30, feat_labels[indices[f]], importances[indices[f]]))
```

[image]

Now I am trying to use `SelectFromModel` from `sklearn.feature_selection` but how can I decide the threshold value for my given dataset.

```
# Create a selector object that will use the random forest classifier to identify
# features that have an importance of more than 0.15
sfm = SelectFromModel(clf, threshold=0.15)

# Train the selector
sfm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I try `threshold=0.15` and then try to train my model I get an error saying data is too noisy or the selection is too strict.

But if I use `threshold=0.015` I am able to train my model on selected new features So how can I decide this threshold value  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try the following approach:

1. start with a low threshold, for example: `1e-4`
2. reduce your features using `SelectFromModel` fit & transform
3. compute metrics (accuracy, etc.) for your estimator (`RandomForestClassifier` in your case) for selected features
4. increase threshold and repeat all steps starting from point 1.

Using this approach you can estimate what is the best `threshold` for your particular data and your estimator